# How to dislodge bluestones sitting in cement? (Pictures)

Tags: cement

[image: Cemensted bluestone border in my garden- no cement between bluestones]

[image: Closer look at the cement the bluestones sit in]

I need to move this wall, but I want to reuse the bluestone for the new wall. So they need to stay whole. Luckily, there isn't any cement between the bluestones-
 they're just sitting in it. 
Has anyone tried to do this before? What tools did you use? Would love some guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Try to wiggle them sideways, to see if they budge at all.

Answer (score 2):

They don't seem to be laid too deep into the ground: excavate the soil behind one of them and try to crank it up from behind with a bar. If it is feeling pretty solid you may have to break that few inches of concrete sitting in front of them with a sledge to loosen them.

Start from a corner or an end stone if you don't want to dig whole lot of soil.

If you can't move them this way you may have to use a jackhammer to open some space around them but I doubt it would come to that.

Comment: A sharp impact At a slightly up angle will probably quickly pop them loose, use a 2×4 scrap to protect from chipping.